# Determine if your build is running as a private build

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

As part of my build i store some of the output if a build is successful. But id rather not do this if its  a private build. Is there a build parameter than i can check so i can skip this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer, thanks to :Michael @ jet brains

"take a look at build.is.personal at Predefined Build Parameters"
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Predefined+Build+Parameters